# How to load the form elements and its attribute dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to load the template and its form elements dynamically.

The desired output:

[image]

I want to load all these fields dynamically so that form should be generic and I can use the same template for all forms in my project.

The code I have tried:

```
<template>
 <b-card>
   <b-row>
            <b-col sm="3">
              <b-form-group>
                <label v-for="option in labelNames">{{ option.name }}</label>
                <input :type="text" :id="name"  :class="form-control" :placeholder="Enter your name" :v-validate="'required|Name'" :name="Firstname" v-model="firstName">
                        <span v-show="errors.has(':name')" class="is-danger">{{ errors.first(':name') }}</span>
               </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            </b-row>
 </b-card>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'addEmpl',
  data () {
    return {
      labelNames: [
        { name: 'FirstName'},
        { name: 'LastName'},
        { name: 'MiddleName'},
        { name: 'EmployeeID'},
        { name: 'Gender'},
        ],
     inputs: [
        { type: 'text', id : 'name1', class : 'form-control' placeholder : 'Enter your name' name: 'Firstname' v-validate : 'required'},
        { type: 'text', id : 'name2', class : 'form-control' placeholder : 'Enter your middle name' name: 'Middlename' v-validate : 'required'},
        { type: 'text', id : 'name3', class : 'form-control' placeholder : 'Enter your last name' name: 'Lastname' v-validate : 'required'},
        ],
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Kindly suggest me a better option to do generic forms. Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't share what is the problem ?

Comment: Also please share live demo if possible ?

Comment: Actucally my problem is, UI becomes empty If I run the above code and I don't know whether it is the correct procedure for dynamic loading or not

Comment: I guess `<b-card>
   <b-row>
            <b-col` these all are component, thats why I was asking for live demo so that we can see all related code and give you working solution

Comment: @Ashwini there is a lot of syntax error in your above code : in data `inputs` your forgot commas between key/value pairs. In your template you try to bind a string as dynamic value (for example for placeholder it should be `:placeholder=" 'Enter your name' "` with double and single quotes, same for the other values)